# MS ACCESS - cannot subtract returned values from a query from values in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables: Project and Invoice

Project Table:

```
ID   |   UR_No   |  Budget_Total  |  Budget_To_Date
1    |  329000   |   150000.00    |
2    |  403952-C |   33000        |
```

Invoice Table:

```
ID   |   URID   |  InvAmount
1    |  329000  |  157.00
2    |  329000  |   32.00
3    |  403952-C|  193.00
```

Invoice table has amounts charged to a project. A project has a unique UR number  (UR_No) and invoices have duplicate UR numbers (URID), meaning the same project gets billed monthly and has different invoice numbers.

What I would like to achieve is:

```
ID   |   UR_No   |  Budget_Total  |  Budget_To_Date
1    |  329000   |   150000.00    |   149811.00
2    |  403952-C |   33000        |   32807
```

First, an aggregate query is done on the Invoice table to get the running total of money charged to the project:

```
SELECT Invoice.URID, Sum(Invoice.InvAmount) AS total
FROM Invoice
GROUP BY Invoice.URID;
```

This returns the following:

```
URID    |  InvAmount
329000  |  189.00
403952-C|  193.00
```

This is then exported to a table in the DB named Invoice_Totals

I then want to join the Invoice_Totals table to the Project table using UR_No & URID and calculate an empty existing field "Budget_to_Date" in the Project table by subtracting Invoice_Totals.total in the query table from a field named Budget_total in the project table. Before attempting that, I would just like the query to return the values:

```
SELECT Project.Budget_Total - Invoice_Totals.total 
FROM Project INNER JOIN Invoice_Totals ON Project.UR_No = Invoice_Totals.URID;
```

This returns the error:
Cannot join on Memo, OLE, or hyperlink object (Project.UR_No=Invoice_Totals.URID)

I looked up an SO post and tried using left 255:

```
SELECT Project.Budget_Total - Invoice_Totals.total 
FROM Project INNER JOIN Invoice_Totals ON left(Project.UR_No,255) = left(Invoice_Totals.URID, 255);
```

This returns nothing. If possible, How can I subtract the aggregate field from budget total in the Project table in either the Budget_To_Date field or in a new field?

Comment: If UR_No and URID are both number types, should be able to join. Is UR_No an autonumber field? Is URID a long integer type? Edit question to provide sample data of both tables as text. I doubt this issue can be blamed on Access. I have never had this problem. Budget_to_Date should not be a field in table. This value should be calculated in query when needed.

Comment: URNO & URID are longtext fields (some of the numbers have letters so had to use this datatype)

Comment: @June7 I added the example tables

Comment: Well, there is source of issue. LongText is synonymous to memo type. Should use ShortText. Surely will never exceed 255 characters. However, really should use ID field in Project table as primary key and save that instead of UR_No into Invoice table. Numbers are more efficient keys.

Comment: @june7 Changed the URID, UR_No to short text and that worked better for the first operation. When I try to subtract the aggregated result in the first query from Project_Budget_Total I get an empty result.                 SELECT Project.Budget_Total - Invoice_Total.total 
FROM Project
INNER JOIN Invoice_Total ON Project.UR_No = Invoice_Total.URID;

Comment: @June7 I figured it out. There was an issue with one of my IDs. It's working now. Can you post your datatype resolution as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment states linking fields are LongText which is synonymous with Memo data type, therefore the error message clearly identifies cause. Change the field type to ShortText.

However, really should use ID field in Project table as primary key and save that instead of UR_No into Invoice table. Numbers are more efficient keys.